# How to exclude specific xml configuration when using @WebMvcTest in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, configuration, integration-testing

I want to test my controller layer, so I used @WebMvcTest annotation, because I don't want startup the whole server. But when I ran the controller test, the test is always failed. My ControllerTest code like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ServiceController.class)
public class ServiceControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@MockBean
private CloudServiceFacade cloudServiceFacade;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void checkRoleExist() throws Exception {
}
}
```

A piece of error messages like :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisPoolConfig' defined in class path resource [tools.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'maxTotal'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${redis.maxTotal}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'maxTotal'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${redis.maxTotal}"
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:596)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:603)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:216)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1538)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1497)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1237)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${redis.maxTotal}"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:468)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:441)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:576)
... 48 more
```

I can understand the error message, because in my application（I use SpringBoot), I have a Bootstrap class which is the entrance of the application.
The Bootstrap class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.netease.permission"})
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class Bootstrap {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Bootstrap.class);
}
}
```

It import a external xml: applicationContext.xml, and applicationContext.xml is below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<import resource="database.xml" />
<import resource="tools.xml" />
<import resource="dubbo-service.xml" />
<import resource="spring-mvc.xml" />

</beans>
```

The problem is I don't want import the whole applicationContext.xml, cause it define the whole extra resource dependency, like mysql\redis\zk,etc. but only spring-mvc.xml.Cause in spring-mvc.xml I define the interceptors. I want test the interceptors & controller in my ServiceControllerTest.

I have already add @TestConfiguration("classpath:spring-mvc.xml") indicate that I only wanna import spring-mvc.xml configuration, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone encounter my situation, could anyone body help?

Answer (score 2):

Just put an empty spring context file with the same file name into src/test/resource folder. This should override the original one.